# How to verifies that, the user is navigated to correct link(Page) in selenium/python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation-testing

**Selenium/Python:**
When I am click on the particular link text, then I am navigated to particular page. I just want to confirm that I navigated to right link.

Comment: compare the link you clicked and the the url to which you are navigated to

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for a site that gives random redirects when a link is clicked?

Calling `driver.current_url` after switching pages will give you the URL of the page you've navigated to. You can then compare that to whatever page you were supposed to navigate to.